# What is it about bleach that keeps Pharaoh ants away even after drying?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I posted this question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108928/what-is-it-about-bleach-that-keeps-pharaoh-ants-away-even-after-drying) and one of the commentors thought that this Chemistry SE might be able to offer more sure answers.

My apartment high-rise has been afflicted with ants in the past few years.  The pest control technician says that it has become a common problem due to warming weather.  Various things have been tried, and I am leaving this in their expert hands (or rather, the apartment management is).  This question is not asking for further countermeasures.

When I find a place or pathway with many ants, I find that simply wiping with a damp cloth or vinegar doesn't keep them away for long.  Wiping is supposed to disrupt their pheromone trails, but I only find somewhat lasting effects if I wipe with undiluted household bleach.  I am pleasantly surprised that they stay away even after the bleach has dried.  After some internet research, I found that bleach leaves behind a salt residue when dried.  **Is it the salt residue that keeps the ants away when wiping otherwise doesn't have lasting effect?**

I've had another corroborative experience that leads me to suspect that salt residue has a repulsive effect on pharaoh ants.  I keep a large beer glass of very salty water on hand because of the dental benefits of salt water rinse.  I probably use too strong a solution, which likely has drawbacks (something I have yet to research).  It is kept on top of the fridge.  Around the glass is salt water staining.  I never see ants around it, even though ants like water.  I admit that this corroboration is not very strong, as I generally do not see ants on top of the fridge anyway.

Comment: This question is admittedly cross-disciplinary (chemical ecology/biology), but probably better suited for biology SE since they can discuss issues such as sensorial thresholds and range of chemical perception and interference, issues that have less to do with basic chemistry and more to do with neurophysiology/ecology/animal behavior.

Comment: However, you might want to explain what kind of chemical answer you are looking for (and I don't think "Is it the salt residue that keeps the ants away when wiping otherwise doesn't have lasting effect?" is a chemical question per se.

Comment: Try an experiment. Leave some of your strong salt solution to dry in an area occupied by the ants and see if they avoid it when it has dried.

Comment: Personally I use butter to convince the ants to stay away. It works. They hate butter.

Comment: @Maurice: Can you please share how you discovered this?  My online surfing indicates that they like fat, and at least one mention of butter.

Comment: @Waylander: I'll keep the dried salt solution in mind.  However, the ants show up in a food preparation area (kitchen counter, often near the sink), so I'm not keen on deviating what seems to work (bleach) for any amount of time.  The sample sizes per day are small (3 to 5 sightings per day, sometimes with application of bleach, often applied at night), so it may take a many-day controlled experiment to be sure.  And the will to avoid wiping down with bleach when I see the ants.

Comment: @ Buck Thorn: OK, thanks for your assessment of the question.  I just didn't know enough to mark the answer as correct in the Biology SE.  Would you have an opinion on that?  I feel that leaving it unmarked is irresponsible, as it could be the right answer.  I just don't know enough about the chemistry to judge.

Comment: I have not discovered the effect of butter. I just got it a couple of years ago in a museum where a real living ants hill was installed by specialists. There was plenty of people  around the nest. And some were asking questions. I remember a visitor asked the specialists how to repell ants from entering his home. The specialist mentionned the butter as an old receipt. I was an auditor, but I remembered it. Much later, I had the opportunity to test the trick at home, and I cut the ants way with a line of butter. It worked. The ants refuse to cross the line, even if it is thin.

Comment: Further web searching reveals that it depends on the ant. If what I read is to be believed, grease ants will love butter, but general ants won't because the the fat makes it hard to digest with their acid. The ant in question here is the Pharaoh ant, which has more of a sweet tooth. [This page](https://www.pesticon.com/ants/how-to-use-boric-acid-to-kill-the-deadly-pharaoh-ants-in-kitchener), however, implies that they like butter, as does [this page](https://smpkhos.go.th/Staff/rustom-real-esuf/pharaoh-ant-diet-185a06). I'll play it safe for now and keep the butter idea for later.

Comment: Household bleach acts as a broad oxidizing agent of organic compounds, and this activity is rapid and usually enough to suppress the original activity of a pheromone. So my assessment would be that the answer at bio SE is correct. The residue is probably table salt. The bio question is, do the ants mind the salt, why or why not? See also: https://www.clorox.com/learn/does-bleach-leave-a-residue-dried-bleach-crystals/

Comment: In retrospect this post seems to contain plenty of chemistry. Feel free to request migration to chem SE at biology SE.

Comment: I did, days ago.  No one responded.  That's why I ended up cross-posting.  Thanks for the vote of confidence in the answer at the Biology SE.  I'll mark it as "the answer".

Comment: My bleach solution seems ill-advised, both because of the fumes and the [adverse effects](https://favoredstoneguides.com/can-you-use-bleach-on-laminate-countertops) on laminate countertops.  It looks as if I will have to get comfortable again with ants on my food preparation surface.